# Which is the justification for this indefinite integral relation?

Tags: integration, trigonometry, substitution

Why is the following indefinite integral equation correct:

$$
\int \frac{\cot(x)}{\sin^2(x)} dx= -\frac{1}{2}\cot^2(x)
$$

What are the necessary steps?

Comment: with $\operatorname{sen}(x)$ you mean the [*sine*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine) function?

Comment: your answer isnot true. just derive the answer it doesnot give the function under integral

Comment: @user190080 is right if sen(x)= sinx then you r right else if sen(x)=secx no  it will be wrong

Comment: @RaziehNoori Just as an aside, the verb form of "derivative" is "differentiate" not "derive".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let $cotx=\dfrac{cosx}{sinx}$ then let $u=sinx$ then $du=cosx dx$

Comment: Sorry, What????

Comment: excuse me let me editt it.

Comment: But, How I get the cot^2 at the end?

Comment: your answer isnot true. just derive the answer it doesnot give the function under integral

Answer (score 1):

$$\int\frac{\cot x}{\sin^2x}\,dx=\int\cot x\csc^2x\,dx$$
Recall that
$$\frac{d}{dx}\cot x=-\csc^2x$$
so substituting $u=\cot x$ will work nicely, since this gives $-du=\csc^2x\,dx$. You then have
$$\int\cot x\csc^2x\,dx=-\int u\,du$$
which gives you the result you're wondering about.

Note that an antiderivative in terms of $\cot x$ isn't the only possible one. I'm referring to the identity,
$$\cot^2x=\csc^2x-1$$